# Fedora Linux: I installed sendmail but now I don't get mail notifications when I log in

Tags: fedora, sendmail

I installed the `sendmail` package on Fedora 23.  So now I have `/usr/sbin/sendmail` that actually kind of works.  Except now I don't get mail notifications in the bash shell.  Why not?

---

EDIT: I thought the bash notification was broken (and worked with esmtp, as described below).  However the notification at login was easier to test, so I'm afraid I conflated the problem.

Notification at login didn't work, but I think that's actually the responsibility of pam_mail, not bash.  I thought notifications at login did work with esmtp, but I notice `grep -r pam_mail /etc/pam.d` doesn't show any results.  Unfortunately enabling pam_mail as per the documentation doesn't seem to do *anything*, even though it's supposed to always print, e.g. "No mail".  It also has a `debug` option, but that didn't display anything to the user nor syslog (aka the journal).

**`mail alan; sleep 60` *does* generate a notification.**

However if I `mail alan; logout` then I don't get any notification when I log in again.  Even after `sleep 60`.  Obviously this is undesirable.

It seems like bash assumes `pam_mail` is working.  So if mail is available at login time, then bash makes sure *not* to notify a second time for the same mail.

So the real problem is that pam_mail is not working.

This realisation required exhaustive tests because I'm dumb.

### Exhaustive tests

If I `mail alan`, then open a second login and run `sleep 60`, I get a notification in one login (only).  It's not obviously a problem with a logout script, because `mail alan; sleep 60` works even if I open a second login and log it out immediately.

Testing with sending mail from a second user, suggests that the notifications don't work if you're not logged in when the mail is sent.

Once bash has shown a notification, it's not showing it again, e.g. after a second `sleep 60`.

I thought it might be comparing the file's access time to the modification time, but that doesn't seem to be the case.

$ stat $MAIL
  File: ‘/var/spool/mail/alan’
  Size: 859         Blocks: 16         IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: fd00h/64768d    Inode: 655929      Links: 1
Access: (0660/-rw-rw----)  Uid: ( 1000/    alan)   Gid: (   12/    mail)
Context: unconfined_u:object_r:mail_spool_t:s0
Access: 2016-05-12 22:17:28.907175410 +0100
Modify: 2016-05-12 22:18:03.177899774 +0100
Change: 2016-05-12 22:18:03.177899774 +0100
 Birth: -

### Environment variables

Example below.  This is after I sent a test mail to myself.  So when I log in, I expect a notification.  If I go on to run `mail`, it shows me the test mail as expected.

```
[alan@localhost ~]$ ssh alan-nuc
Last login: Thu May 12 20:50:54 2016 from 172.16.9.242

[alan@alan-nuc ~]$ echo $MAIL
/var/spool/mail/alan
[alan@alan-nuc ~]$ ls -l $MAIL
-rw-rw----. 1 alan mail 850 May 12 20:56 /var/spool/mail/alan
[alan@alan-nuc ~]$ echo $MAILCHECK
60
[alan@alan-nuc ~]$ echo $MAILPATH

[alan@alan-nuc ~]$
```

### Installing sendmail

Fedora Workstation ships with a non-working `/bin/sendmail` (esmtp package).

It can be set up by install maildrop and setting `mda="maildrop -d %T" in /etc/esmtprc`.  This allows mail from a user to themself, and from root to anyone.  **With esmtp and maildrop, bash shows mail notifications as expected**.

However esmtp doesn't work for mails from the `cron` daemon.  esmtp logs "permission denied" when trying to read the message to deliver.  https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1303305  Specifically, when trying to re-open `/dev/stdin`, which is generally expected to succeed (equivalent to `dup()`).  So it's probably SELinux, but there is no SELinux (AVC) denial logged, it's probably `dontaudit`.

Installing the old sendmail package replaces the sendmail command provided by esmtp.  I thought that would be a simple way to bypass the new bugs, but now I have yet another bug :(.

Comment: perhaps the partly-working package provides incoming mail in a different directory than you expect.

Comment: @ThomasDickey Good point but no.  I can see mail being delivered to `/var/spool/mail` in both cases.

Comment: This is strange.  It's `bash` that does the checking of mail, so it should be independent of the MTA.  My guess is that `MAIL`, `MAILPATH`, and/or `MAILCHECK` isn't set properly in your shell.

Comment: Indeed, but I've checked the environment variables now and I can't see what's wrong! See updated question.

Comment: Update: turns out I was testing wrong. However bash mail notifications assume that pam_mail is working. Unfortunately it's not, and so far I've failed to either enable or debug it.

Comment: Since you're using `ssh` to get in, what's `/etc/pam.d/sshd` look like?

Comment: Thanks! That file doesn't contain pam_mail, nor include one that does.  I believed the manpage that said to add it in `/etc/pam.d/login`, so it sounds like that's the problem. I feel like I should credit you with the bounty now :). If you want to phrase that as an answer (however short), then I will mark it as accepted. (I might edit it longer though).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Configuration for reporting on the status of mail at login time is handled by `pam_mail`.  Check the corresponding file (e.g. `/etc/pam.d/ssh`) and make sure that you have a line that looks something like this:

```
session    optional     pam_mail.so standard noenv
```

May be different depending on your distribution.  Check your distro documentation to see how it should be set.