# cron mail on Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, email

On my Debian system I have a traditional local-only "mail" setup.  The package install set up some sensible default. (Maybe it prompted me to accept the settings; I don't remember).

EDIT: In Debian 9 and above, `exim4-daemon-light` is no longer installed as part of the Debian "standard task" (package set).

The main reason this is useful is for errors in `cron` jobs (and also `at` jobs), which are delivered as local "mail".

```
$ aptitude why exim4-daemon-light
i   exim4 Depends exim4-daemon-light | exim4-daemon-heavy | exim4-daemon-custom
```

```
$ aptitude why exim4
i   logrotate Depends    cron | anacron | cron-daemon          
i A cron      Recommends exim4 | postfix | mail-transport-agent
```

Fedora Workstation does not include a functioning mail setup.  You have to choose to install it, *and* you probably need to do some [extra configuration](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/280182/fedora-linux-i-installed-sendmail-but-now-i-dont-get-mail-notifications-when-i#comment492396_280182).

Ubuntu is based on Debian.  On Ubuntu Desktop, assuming you installed `cron` (or `at`), will you have a (working) local mail setup for it?

EDIT: I guess on Debian 9 you already need to choose to install a mail system if you want one, despite the "Recommends".

(I have written some Ansible stuff which sets up cron jobs on a Debian system.  I expect to switch the system to Ubuntu Desktop eventually.  So I am thinking about the assumptions my scripts are making).

Comment: The recent Debian 9 comes with no MTA neither.

Comment: And the cron package has the same  "you should probably install ..." info.

Comment: Recommends: exim4 | postfix | mail-transport-agent

Comment: @Tomasz again, thanks. I've added "EDIT" lines to avoid spreading mis-information. The original question sort of depended on my confusion about this point, so that seemed the easiest way to address it.

Comment: You can also find it here: https://packages.debian.org/en/jessie/cron Maybe the recommendations are a bug, I don't know. Their changelog doesn't work for me now, so I can't tell when the change was introduced.

Comment: @Tomasz I think ideally the "Recommends" would be removed, but cron would log to the system log. I added two more paragraphs at the end of my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ubuntu Desktop 18.04 does not include `cron`.

If you do install `cron`, it will *not* automatically install a mail transport agent.  The Ubuntu `cron` package no longer "Recommends" any "mail transport agent" packages.

(This feels like another inconsistency, as the package description for cron still says "you should probably install a mail system as well so that you can receive these messages".  They didn't bother adding a `Suggests` in place of the `Recommends`... probably because no-one would really notice if they did anyway.)

Also, there is a link in the question about `pam_mail`.  It looks like a default install of Ubuntu Desktop 18.04 still includes `pam_mail` lines in `/etc/pam.d/*` - unlike Fedora Workstation.

If you do not need mail specifically, you might be interested in `systemd-cron`. Apparently it logs cronjob output to the system log.  If a mail system is available, it additionally sends any output as a mail.

[Patches were submitted in 2012](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=670118) to provide similar feature in the Debian `cron` package.  The description of the patch says that by default, it will only log output if it could not send a mail.  So far, the ticket has not been closed.  So at the moment, if a cronjob generates output, the specific output may be lost.  This is logged as an informational message; it is not marked as a warning or an error.

```
Jul 27 16:36:01 debian9-vm CRON[2337]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Jul 27 16:36:01 debian9-vm CRON[2338]: (root) CMD (echo fail; exit 1)
Jul 27 16:36:01 debian9-vm CRON[2337]: (CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)
Jul 27 16:36:01 debian9-vm CRON[2337]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
```